Slick 3.5.1 LocalDateTime parser taking only 3 nanosecond numbers
I am using scala slick library 3.5.1. I have implemented DB tables for Oracle profiles with LocalDateTime columns. When trying to select data, insert data I am getting
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

It is because java.LocalDateTime.now() for example can return 9 nanoseconds like this (2024-09-30T14:23:58.583936100) and slick oracle profile localdatetime is accepting only 3 nanosecond numbers.
column definition
def startDate = column[LocalDateTime]("START_DATE")

query to get data
val date = LocalDateTime.now()

(for {
  reservation <- reservations
  if reservation.startDate >= date.bind
} yield reservation).result

SQL generated by slick library:
select * from tbl_reservations
where startDate >= TO_TIMESTAMP ('30-Sep-24 14:10:10.583936100', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF3');

Is there any way how to resolve this issue in scala for the whole project (like overriding oracle profile ...) ?

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the code you are using to generate the tables (and the DDL statements that generates if you are using an ORM to generate code); and the code to SELECT and INSERT data (including the generated Oracle queries). We cannot debug code that we cannot see.

Oracle does not have a LocalDateTime data type. It has DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE. They all have a time component but the 3 TIMESTAMP types can have fractional seconds and can specify the precision (i.e. TIMESTAMP(6) can store micro-seconds).

As I have mentioned I am using slick scala library where you can define column type as LocalDateTime and it will map to TIMESTAMP oracle type.

Your error is caused by TO_TIMESTAMP ('30-Sep-24 14:10:10.583936100', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF3'). FF3 is 3 digits and you are providing 9 and the mismatch is why Oracle raises an exception. You either want FF9 in the format model or to round the fractional seconds to 3 digits.

I am trying to find some workaround, because the format i have posted is part of slick scala library. i have also posted an issue to slick scala library project, but need to make it working, so thinking about some custom profile setting or something like thaht.

Have you checked slick - 3.5.1 - datetime types? There is a paragraph that talks about using LocalDateTime and add some details about Oracle

It sounds like your library is converting the date and time to and from a string, which it shouldn’t. Anyway a thought, LocalDateTime.now(yourDesiredZoneId) .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLISECONDS). Only wondering and worried what will then happen when once in a while you hot a whole second or even a whole minute.
